# Regarding microsoft azure polices - DeployIfNotExists

Tags: azure, tags, azure-bicep, azure-policy

I deploy a policy via bicep that checks if a virtual machine has the tag 'BackupRetention' and that is filled in with 1 of the 4 specific retentions
How ever i keep getting back non compliances. aswell for non compliant ( a vm that doesnt have the tag) and a vm that has the correct tagging.

Policyruleset:

```
if: {
        allOf: [
          {
            field: 'type'
            equals: 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
          }
          {
          anyOf: [
            {
              
              field: 'tags[\'BackupRetention\']'
              notEquals: 'backup-week'
            }
            {
              field: 'tags[\'BackupRetention\']'
              notEquals: 'backup-day'
            }
            {
              field: 'tags[\'BackupRetention\']'
              notEquals: 'backup-month'
            }
            {
              field: 'tags[\'BackupRetention\']'
              notEquals: 'backup-year'
            }
          ]
        }
        ]
      }
      then: {
        effect: 'modify'
        details: {
          roleDefinitionIds: [
            '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c' // Contributor role
          ]
          operations: [
            {
              operation: 'addOrReplace'
              field: 'tags[\'BackupRetention\']'
              value: 'None' // replace with the value you want to set
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Non Compliant messages:

```
Reason for non-compliance
Current value must not be equal to the target value.
Field
type
Current value
"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
Target value
"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
Reason for non-compliance
Current value must be equal to the target value.
Field
tags['BackupRetention']
Current value
"backup-week"
Target value
"backup-day"
```

I tried several options , even the modify parameter ... does not work.
Im kinda pulling my hair out.

Comment: Shouldn't `anyOf` be part of `allOf`? If it's none of the allowed values it should trigger the policy.

Comment: hi Peter... yes.. i just came by that also now. sometimes looking away for an hour sometimes works :( thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

```
anyOf: [
        {
          
          field: 'tags[\'BackupRetention\']'
          notEquals: 'backup-week'
        }
        {
          field: 'tags[\'BackupRetention\']'
          notEquals: 'backup-day'
        }
        {
          field: 'tags[\'BackupRetention\']'
          notEquals: 'backup-month'
        }
        {
          field: 'tags[\'BackupRetention\']'
          notEquals: 'backup-year'
        }
      ]
```

This block needs allOf instead of anyOf